# Possible way to speed up SUMO simulation

Tags: simulation

Hi all I am a new SUMO user. I am having simulation iteratively with DUAROUTER and SUMO. The simulation consist of 20000 trips in Singapore network and it's very slow, took one hour and more to complete one simulation.

Anyone knows any way to speed up the process? I need to do 50 iterations. 1 hour per iteration is too slow.

My commands are as follows:

```
duarouter --net-file sg_left_v1.net.xml --trip-files trips20000_merged.trips.xml --output-file 0.20000.route.xml --ignore-errors true --no-warnings true --repair true

sumo -c simulation_sg_20000.sumocfg --tripinfo-output 0.20000.trip.output.xml --no-warnings true --tripinfo-output.write-unfinished true --vehroute-output 0.20000.individual.output.xml --link-output 0.20000.link-state.output.xml
```

The number X in X.20000.something.xml is increased on each iteration by my python code.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I dont know if it is possible since the simulation speed is intrinsic to the SUMO.

Answer (score 0):

There are different things you can do to speed up the process by analyzing the bottlenecks. I would do the following:

1. Check whether the traffic flow is smooth. If there are big jams piling up the simulation slows down.
2. Do the vehicles depart at the times you expect them too. Even is there no visible jam, the backlog slows the simulation down. A good indicator is that vehicles which have an intended departure time near the end of the simulation, take much longer to depart (it's also in the tripinfo).
3. Recheck whether you need all outputs. To get a feeling whether it helps disable them one by one and have a look at the running time.

   3a. Extend SUMO to aggregate your data. It is open source after all, so if the outputs are the bottleneck, aggregate inside the simulation.
4. Think about parallel execution. Maybe you do not need to start the iterations one after another?
5. Make the scenario smaller.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. Your suggestions were reasonable. But I can't run execution in parallel manner. After each iteration, I will analyse the output data (of course all the analysis and command for each iteration are done by self written program automatically), and check for the mean speed for each edge. If the mean speed is not satisfactory (say it is less than 50% of the rated speed), I will add weight to it so that for the next iteration, some vehicles might be finding another route, therefore reduce jam.

Comment: Or have I misunderstood the use of weight? My understanding for weight is, the bigger the weight of one edge, vehicles will be less likely routed via that edge.

Comment: Your understanding is right. Larger weights make an edge less attractive.

Comment: Another understanding I have for weights is that weights are like "virtual length" of the edges. They will replace the original edge lengths when the algorithm behind is making decision on which edge to take to acquire the shortest path. Is it correct also? I am having bad results even after adjusting the weight.

Comment: It does not really matter whether you think of the weight in terms of length, travel time or fuel consumption. It is only important to note that the smaller the better and that there is a value for each edge (and the value for the route is the sum of the edge values along the route).

Answer (score 0):

To accelerate the simulation, you will need to pass a parameter to Sumo called step-length
which a ratio of sumoTime / realWorldtime.

```
sumo your-other-args-here --step-length 1
```

It should enable you the get the wanted result